# Typescript Map function return different types after mapping

Tags: typescript, overloading

I have three interfaces

```
interface A {
  productId: string;
  productName?: string;
  quantity: number;
}
```

```
interface B {
  productId: string;
  productName?: string;
  company: string;
}
```

```
interface Product {
  id: string;
  name: string;
```

I have arrays of each interface. For ex, this is for Product

```
[{productId: '1', productName: 'pen', productId: '2', productName: 'paper'}]
```

I want to map through my arrays of A and B, filter to find the corresponding product in the Product array and add it to each item. Here's my function

```
const addProductNameToLineItem = (
  products: Product[],
  items: A[] | B[]
): A[] | B[] => {
  return items.map((item) => {
    const productInfo = products?.find(
      (product: Product) => product.id === item?.productId
    );
    return {
      ...item,
      productName: productInfo?.name
    };
  });
};
```

This doesn't work, I'm getting a type error that the result is not assignable to type A[] | B[].

I tried a function overload and couldn't get it to work.

If I break up the function and duplicate it (one that expects only items A and one that expects only items B) then it works fine.

Comment: You aren't returning anything, and also, `...productName: productInfo?.name` is invalid syntax. Can you correct these mistakes?

Comment: Thank you, @caTS. Is that better? Sorry, I'm copying off my code and trying to generalize it, so I missed some things. 

The resulting array does work and has the correct shape, but I'm struggling with the type errors

Comment: Your problem is you declared your arrays as *all* of type `A` or  *all* of type `B`, so it can't identify the common type despite the fact you tried to trick it by using the same name.  I'd restort to making a templated type function if you know the type upstream or having `A` and `B` derive from a common class with `productName` and use that

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your function *generic*:

```
const addProductNameToLineItem = <Item extends A | B>(
  products: Product[],
  items: Item[]
): Item[] => {
```

This means the return type is coherent with what you pass - for example, if I give it `A[]`, I should expect to be given `A[]`. Previously, if I give it `A[]`, I was given `A[] | B[]`, which is incorrect.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mppdbm)

Comment: I was going to say `T extends {productId: string, productName?: string}` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m36LbN) but this is fine too, I guess